# How long does it take to close an FTP connection?

Tags: ftp

Let's say that there is a file transfer from client to server, and the client wants to cancel the transfer. How long would this take?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by having this information?  The answer to this question is it happens immediately?  So the amount of time it takes is measure in the milliseconds.

Comment: What's your definition of "cancel"?

Answer (score 0):

### 0 seconds

You can cancel it in the program used, you can kill the program or you can kill the computer (pull the plug). The latter two are basically instantaneous.